# kubernetes: How multiple containers inside a pod use localhost

Tags: kubernetes

I see that kubernets uses pod and then in each pod there can be multiple containers.

Example I create a pod with

```
Container 1: Django server - running at port 8000
Container 2: Reactjs server - running at port 3000
```

Since the containers inside cant have port conflicts, then its better to put all of them in one containers. Because I see the advantage of using containers is no need to worry about port conflict.

```
Container 1: BOTH Django server - running at port 8000 and Reactjs server - running at port 3000
```

No need of container2.

and also

When i run different docker containers on my PC i cant access them like local host

But then how is this possible inside a POD with multiple containers.

Whats the difference between the docker containers run on PC and inside a POD.

Answer (score 2):

The typical way to think about this delineation is "which parts of my app scale together?"

So for your example, you probably wouldn't even choose a common pod for them. You should have a Django pod and separately, a ReactJS server pod. Thus you can scale these independently.

The typical case for deploying pods with multiple containers is a pattern called "sidecar", where the added container enhances some aspect of the deployed workload, and always scales right along with that workload container. Examples are:

1. Shipping logs to a central log server
2. Security auditing
3. Purpose-built Proxies - e.g. handles DB connection details
4. Service Mesh (intercepts all network traffic and handles routing, circuit breaking, load balancing, etc.)

As for deploying the software into the same container, this would only be appropriate if the two pieces being considered for co-deployment into the same container are developed by the same team and address the same concerns (that is - they really are only one piece when you think about it). If you can imagine them being owned/maintained by distinct teams, let those teams ship a clean container image with a contract to use networking ports for interaction.

(some of) The details are this:
Pods are a shared Networking and IPC namespace. Thus one container in a pod can modify iptables and the modification applies to all other containers in that pod. This may help guide your choice: Which containers should have *that* intimate a relationship to each other?
Specifically I am referring to Linux Namespaces, a feature of the kernel that allows different processes to share a resource but not "see" each other. Containers are normal Linux processes, but with a few other Linux features in place to stop them from seeing each other. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGw_xKF47T0&t=369s) is a great intro to these concepts. (timestamp in link lands on a succinct slide/moment)

Edit - I noticed the question edited to be more succinctly about networking. The answer is in the Namespace feature of the Linux kernel that I mentioned. Every process belongs to a Network namespace. Without doing anything special, it would be the default network namespace. Containers usually launch into their own network namespace, depending on the tool you use to launch them. Linux then includes a feature where you can virtually connect two namespaces - this is called a Veth Pair (Pair of Virtual Ethernet devices, connected). After a Veth pair is setup between the default namespace and the container's namespace, both get a new eth device, and can talk to each other. Not all tools will setup that veth pair by default (example: Kubernetes will not do this by default). You can, however, tell Kubernetes to launch your pod in "host" networking mode, which just uses the system's default network namespace so the veth pair is not even required.

Comment: `: Pods are a shared Networking and IPC namespace` can you throw some light on this

Comment: You got it - check out the linked video, it's a gem!

Comment: where is the video

Comment: I edited answer - refresh to see it.

Comment: Also I noticed your edit to the question, I will edit again to add a bit more detail.

Comment: got it thanks. I will check this

Comment: great video. really feeling what containers are

Comment: Awesome! I love pointing to that video whenever I present K8s!

Comment: can you check the another question i asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71389824/kubernetes-is-pod-is-also-like-a-pc